# How can i check if a param exists with jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need a JSTL expression or a tag which checks that the availability of `param` in request.

Comment: How can i validate  if a param is null or empty using the s tags of JSTL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.itemId == null}">
    <fmt:message key="Add" />
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <fmt:message key="Edit"/>      
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `c:if` tag to test if variable or say `${param["xyz"]}` exists or not like:

```
 <c:if test="${empty parameter}">
     parameter is empty or null.
 </c:if>
```